# Can I move a div using javascript and retain its postback ability?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, postback, prototypejs

I've got a list of checkboxes and an ImageButton with an OnClick event in my page, clicking the ImageButton performs a postback and runs the OnClick event fine

The trouble is that I want to move the div to be the first child of the `<form>` so that I can make it appear in a modal window - I've done this using the prototype.js code...

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {

    if ($$('.CheckboxListContainer').length>0) {    

        var modalShadow = document.createElement('div');
        modalShadow.setAttribute( "class", 'MyFormModalShadow' );

        modalShadow.style.width = document.viewport.getWidth() + 'px';
        modalShadow.style.height = document.viewport.getHeight() + 'px';

        var modalDiv = document.createElement('div');
        modalDiv.setAttribute( "class", 'MyFormModal' );

        var checkboxesDiv = $$('.CheckboxListContainer')[0];
        checkboxesDiv.remove();

        modalDiv.appendChild( checkboxesDiv );

        $$('form')[0].insert( {top: modalShadow} );
        $$('form')[0].insert( {top: modalDiv} );

        Event.observe(window, "resize", function() {
            if ($$('.MyFormModalShadow').length>0) {
                var modalShadow = $$('.MyFormModalShadow')[0]
                modalShadow.style.width = document.viewport.getWidth() + 'px';
                modalShadow.style.height = document.viewport.getHeight() + 'px';
            }
        });

    }

});
```

... which works fine, but the ImageButton is no longer triggering my OnClick event on postback.

Is there a way to move my div around in the DOM and retain its postback abilities?

Comment: What happens when you remove the line `checkboxesDiv.remove();`? Also, what happens when you click the image button? Is the page reloaded?

Comment: Removing checkboxesDiv.remove(); doesn't change the outcome of the code (and the postback is still not triggered), I just wanted to make sure that the element was fully removed before adding it back in somewhere else. Yes, the page reloads when you click the image button

Comment: Quick test showed me that moving the button didn't "ruin" the PostBack event.. how can you tell "the ImageButton is no longer triggering my OnClick event"? Did you put break point and debugged?

Comment: Yep I put in a break point and debugged. I've actually ended up just calling my onclick event in the page load which works as it's simple one purpose control

Comment: Weird. But how can you tell if the button was clicked in the `Page_Load`? If you'll have more than one button, simple `if (Page.IsPostBack)` won't be good idea.

Comment: I can't tell if the button was clicked in Page_Load, it's a solution which only works for me as it's a really simple control. So not a great resolution to my problem, but one that will have to do

Answer (score 4):

Quick answer, yes. Long answer below:

If you're talking ASP.NET WebForms, does your form have the `runat="server"` attribute and an id? If you're using standard HTML, are the `method` and `action` attributes set on the form?

When you look at the HTML source in your browser, if the form looks like: `<form action="/your_post_back_page.html" method="post">`,  then that's all good. Inspect the form with FireBug *after the modal dialog has been added*, see if it is INSIDE the form tags. If so, that's good.

Do your check boxes `<input type="checkbox" />` have a `name` attribute set? Is your image button `<input type='submit' />` or is it a `<button>`?

If these conditions are met, then there is probably a JavaScript event (a function) wired to your button that is returning false and/or swallowing the postback. JavaScript `onclick` events generally need to return true to submit a form. Is there any output in your browser's error console?

Personally, I find more and more that pure HTML (by way of ASP.NET MVC) beats the pants off old school ASP.NET WebForms, and jQuery has, in my experience, a far nicer feel than prototype. Using jQuery templates to create a modal dialog would be easy. Can you swap libraries?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, i am not very clear why you need to move the element to be the first child of the form to make it modal. You can make any div modal no matter where is the position in the form. The most important think is controlling the absolute positioning properly.

Each postback gets triggered by a __DoPostBack() javascript function, so you should not have any issues with moving the control around, unless you changed the id of the control.

One possible solution to your problem is calling the __DoPostBack() function from your client code in document.ready, and that way you have full control over the form submission.